# Testing an RCD switch by short circuiting neutral and ground

Tags: rcd

*This question has some implications on home related work with mains. Never take what you read on the internet as the truth when lives might be in the line. That is how I'll be treating potential answers also.*

---

I've seen references which claim it's a valid test to connect the Ground and Neutral to test if the RCD switch will break.

I've made a simple schematic of the problem and marked the point where the current has to leak to make this test successful.

There seems to be a lot of parameters which could result in this test giving a false negative. i.e.:

- current going through Neutral too small
- big resistance to Ground
- RCD breaking current high

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZFui7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For some reason someone thought this was a good test. I've done it at home and it always works for a 30mA RCD. So it's possible that even thought I can't seem to theoretically justify it might of have empirically proven itself like a good enough test in the field.

Would like to hear if it's possible to defend or disprove this approach on both a theoretical and practical level?

Could this test be enhanced by connecting, say, a 9V battery (+ on Neutral, - on Ground)?

Are there other simple ways to test if RCD works for a particular socket? I've sadly seen wiring of the house retrofitted so only some sockets actually have the Ground wire and others just look like that externally but only N and L are on the socket.

Comment: The RCD only detects current that flows from hot to ground rather than hot to neutral. You have not drawn the test link properly. The test link should not be a short circuit, it should be a resistance that draws just a little more than the RCD test current rating.

Comment: PE Gnd is just a safety ground and never needed for RCD operation or testing. Only the imbalance or differential of current between Line and Neural is needed.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 `PE Gnd is just a safety ground and never needed for RCD operation or testing`. Am not with you in this one. Perhaps that might be true in theory, however in practice the current has to go somewhere when there is a fault. If there in no ground, the RCD will break when someone touches the appliance. It isn't self evident that is a benign shock :)

Comment: The earth is required for proving that the test switch operates.

Comment: TheMeaningfulEngineer  If you "aren't with me" then you do not understand yet. Do you see any Gnd wire in Andy's 1st diagram? It is not used for proving it works but it is used to detect unsafe ground leakage current from Line voltage with the same unbalanced current effect. Do you agree @Andyaka ?  I agree with Andy's answer but not comment above unless there  is doubt with the test button is what he meant.

Comment: For example even with an open PE ground fault an RCD can detect leakage to earthed plumbing (non plastic)

Comment: @tony, what I was saying is that you can test to earth (and I believe some will do this) but, in the main, just an imbalance is good enough and, kidding the toroid there is an imbalance is good enough. That is or can be achieved without an earth wire. I agree with your top comment other than I think some RCDs will “test” using a pukka earth connection. Prior to RCDs, ELCBs were used and they literally monitored earth return from an appliance to see if there was Earth Leakage and, if there was tripped the CB hence the acronym ELCB.

Comment: Yes the false test results with a ground fault made those old ones obsolete @Andy  . Over here we called them GFI's but they never relied on  PE for sensing,

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I was referring to your part regarding operation of the RCD. If there isn't a ground (not in the RCD but in the house wiring) and the RCD detected a leak, a human was likely electrified before the RCD reacted. So in theory, the RCD can detect a leakage without a ground, but it practice it's not a good safety mechanism in that case.

Answer (score 1):

> I've seen references which claim it's a valid test to connect the
>   Ground and Neutral to test if the RCD switch will break.

That is only reliable if the potential difference between neutral and earth is sufficient to drive circa 30 mA through the RCD when neutral and earth are connected. However, it is a fail safe technique to some extent.

> Are there other simple ways to test if RCD works for a particular
>   socket?

What's wrong with using the test switch on an RCD: -

[image]

All (?) RCDs appear to use test switches: -

[image]

[Google results of "RCD test switch circuit"](https://www.google.com/search?q=RCD+test+switch+circuit&safe=strict&rlz=1C1DIMC_enGB828GB828&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiS7veMnZLnAhUAUBUIHTpJDM0Q_AUoAXoECA0QAw&biw=1493&bih=895#imgrc=_) appears to show all RCDs with test switches and, where there are schematics, they all seem to use a resistor from live to earth to create the earth imbalance current.

Including wall sockets: -

[image]

> Would like to hear if it's possible to defend or disprove this
>   approach on both a theoretical and practical level?

I can neither defend or disprove this approach because if it does work then it's likely the RCD is OK but, you haven't proven that in the right way.

Comment: Same as the ones used in North America except at a much lower trip level of < 5mA which can cause false trips in some humid shower & dust situations or burnt toast in high humidity but apparently Europeans are more hardy to shock limits ;)

Comment: `What's wrong with using the test switch on an RCD?`

It tests the switch and not "is the switch working with a particular socket". Thanks for the reference on the "earth to live" switch. I guess that's the only real test. Would be great to find a safe testing device that could do that for an indivisual socket but not trigger a fuse.

Comment: European philosophy: It might hurt a lot the first time but you'll never do it again or, if you do, you'll suffer Darwinian decline. @Tony

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer yes, it tests the switch but it also tests the series resistor and live/earth connection. If the test switch doesn't work then the problem is either switch, resistor, live wire or earth wire; in that case an electrician needs to be called in.

Comment: @Andyaka On the schematics you posted seems like the the hot wire goes through a coil before the resistor and the test switch. You know why didn't they just skip the coil?

Comment: No wait, sorry. The RCD tests short circuits Hot and Neutral... Why would that event break the switch?

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer there are two meaningful ways of testing the imbalance transformer and one way connects live to earth (at the output); the other way simulates a current to earth by connecting live (after the imbalance transformer) via the resistor to neutral (prior to the imbalance transformer). This 2nd way does not have a return balancing current passing via neutral and hence it mimics the live-earth fault current.

Comment: I don't  see why there is a separate sensing coil for the test switch. All the test switch should need to do is create a path for current from hot to neutral that bypasses the neutral conductor that goes through the core.

Comment: @CharlesCowie possibly because the test current is low and therefore needs to be magnified by the number of turns.

Comment: The test current should be equal to the differential that is rated to trip the device.

Comment: @Andyaka It seems the two images/schematics aren't the same. The second one does bypass the neutral going through the core. But the second switch looks to me just like shorting a hot and neutral on a socket (they are on the same side of the coil). That shouldn't break the switch.

Comment: The first one has equal currents passing and returning through the core via the main wires but there is the extra coil that does the imbalancing. Both look good to me @TheMeaningfulEngineer

Comment: @CharlesCowie I would say that the flux has to be right and if lower current and more turns gets that flux then it should work. After all, the toroid is acting like a current transformer and we now if the main conductor is looped through the aperture of a CT twice, we get twice the current at the output flowing in the burden.

Comment: The plug-in testers for the USA GFI receptacles work by simply connecting a resistor from hot to PE. That means they won't work if PE is not connected. In the example that I have disassembled on my desk, the test appears to connect a 2500 ohm resistor between hot on the output side and neutral on the input side without going through a winding on the sensing core. The sensing core is difficult to examine because it is in an assembly with a second toroid that is apparently a transformer that supplies power to the trip relay circuit. This GFCI was installed in 1984.

Comment: @Andyaka You mean because the test has 2 winds on the test circuit vs the 3 winds for the trip relay? :D Good eyes, missed that.

Comment: No I don’t mean that. The third winding (first two being live and neutral wires that pass straight through) does the imbalancing.  The sense Winding is used to “measure” the discrepancy and trigger the breaker / trip relay. However many turns that has on it is immaterial to the concept.